R Lubridate: Calculate the interval in minutes between two datetimes, but only considering specific hours of the day?
I have a list of start times and end times. Something like:
data <- data.frame(start_time = c(ymd_hms("2024-01-04 12:05:00"), 
                                  ymd_hms("2024-01-05 06:15:00"), 
                                  ymd_hms("2024-01-03 21:08:00")),
                   end_time=c(ymd_hms("2024-01-04 16:35:00"), 
                               ymd_hms("2024-01-05 11:30:00"), 
                               ymd_hms("2024-01-06 13:00:00")))

I would like to calculate the difference in minutes between these 2 dates. This is easily done with the difftime() function.
However, I need to only consider a specific time window during the day e.g. between 9am and 5pm.
For example, the second example above has a start time of 2024-01-05 06:15:00 and an end time of 2024-01-05 11:30:00. As the start time falls outside of these specific hours (9-5), I don't want to include this as part of the duration. So, the actual answer I would like is from 2024-01-05 09:00:00 to 2024-01-05 11:30:00 which gives an interval of 150 minutes.
The three answers I expect for the examples above are 270 mins, 150 mins and 1200 mins respectively.
Is there a way I can easily do this in R/lubridate/any other package?
Thanks
